# Generate Unique Id's when using Knockout ko.observableArray([]) foreach and there is multiple Textboxes being created in Dom

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

An Accordian is Created

```
<div id="accordian">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div id="SoftwareIssueSelection" data-bind="foreach: SoftwareViewModel.items">


                <h3 class="AccordianResSoftwareDiv"><a data-bind="text: $data.issueItemHeader" href="#"></a></h3>

                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <div class="panel box box-primary">
                        <div class="callout callout-info">
                          <h2 data-bind="text: $data.issueItemBody"></h2><br />
                          <p data-bind="text: $data.issueItemExtraInfo"><b></b></p>
                          <p><b>Please Tell Us More..</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="EmailSelectedItem" class="form-group has-feedback">
                          <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceRequestEmail, new { data_bind = "value:$data.serviceRequestEmail", @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Please Enter Email" })</div>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                          <label id="ContactNoLabel" class="control-label" for="inputError">
                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Cannot be Left Blank
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="LocationSelectedItem" class="form-group has-feedback">
                          <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceRequestLocation, new {  data_bind = "value:$data.serviceRequestLocation", @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Please Enter Location" })</div>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk form-control-feedback"></span>
                          <label id="ContactNoLabel" class="control-label" for="inputError">
                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Cannot be Left Blank
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="ContactNoSelected" class="form-group has-feedback">
                          <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceRequestContactNo, new { data_bind = "value:$data.serviceRequestContactNo", @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Please Enter Contact No." })</div>
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
                          <label id="ContactNoLabel" class="control-label" for="inputError">
                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Cannot be Left Blank
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:black">
                            <a href="#" id="submitSelectedIssueRepoItemToServiceRequest" data-bind="click: $parent.itemClicked.bind($data,{id: @Model.Client.id}, $index())" class="small-box-footer">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>                 
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>          
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And Each TextboxFor is generated with the Same Id For each li in the ul as one loops through  ko.observableArray([])

How Do You Create UniqueIds For Each TextboxFor element is the dom thats being repeated?

Answer (score 0):

Within a `foreach` binding, the `$index` observable is available, which you can use to create unique IDs.

```
data-bind="attr: { id: 'item-' + $index() }"
```

Comment: Good Day i originally tried this This will Not Work as the form will be repeated for each accordion item so TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceRequestEmail will receive Id of item_1 and for the next form item TextBoxFor(m => m.ServiceRequestEmail, will receive the same Id of item_1

Comment: I see! If it's a nested `foreach` (that is, the accordion items are created with a `foreach` as well), you could use `$parentContext.$index()` and `$index()` together to create unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved It What i did was add a function to my viewModel and from my CSHTML I Then called this function Which Generates a UniqueID and returns it to DOM

```
  createRandomId: function (name) {
  var uniqueId = name + '_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
  return uniqueId;
  }


  data_bind = "attr: {id: SoftwareViewModel.createRandomId('SoftwareItemUnique')}
```

Thank You Team